# Eclipse - Pass file path as argument

Tags: java, eclipse, bufferedreader

```
public static Graph loadFromFile(String infile, boolean is_undirected) throws IOException {
    Graph g = new Graph();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infile));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
        int src = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        int dst = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        g.addEdge(src, dst);
        if (is_undirected) {
            g.addEdge(dst, src);
        }
    }
    br.close();
    return g;
}
```

this is part of code from one class;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("java Influencers INFILE [u|d]");
        return;
    } 
    Graph g = Graph.loadFromFile(args[0], args[1].equals("u"));
    run(g);
}
```

this is the main function, So for now I want to assign a txt file named xx.txt to the filereader, how do I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From Command Promt**

To run a Java program, you must first compile it.
To compile a package, run the following from the directory of the padckage

```
javac *.java -d .
```

You can pass the File path as command line argument during your program run.

```
java ${your_package_name}.${your_main_class_name} xx.txt u
```

For example, if the package name is `a.b.c` and the main class name is `Main`, run

```
java a.b.c.Main xx.txt u
```

[Reference](https://blog.miyozinc.com/java/java-command-line-arguments/)

**From Eclipse IDE**

1. Click on **Run** -> **Run Configurations**
2. Click on **Arguments** tab 
   [image: arguments tab]
3. In Program Arguments , Enter your arguments. Each separated by a whitespace.
   *xx.txt u*
4. Then Click **Apply**, followed by **Run**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir but I'm using JAVA eclipse, When I run the code above the output is the "java Influencers INFILE [u|d]" which means I didn't pass the file name to the bufferedreader in the main function I guess, so i wonder know the the way to assign the txt file to the file reader in main function. (BTW the txt file is in the eclipse-project-default package)

Comment: Edited the answer for Eclipse IDE, Pass the full file path *c:\myproject\xx.txt* as the file path argument

Comment: It's work thank you very much..  and...is there another way to pass parameter in the main function?I mean we don't pass parameter by adding text in the argument section, instead pass it by compiling code at the part of main function？

Comment: You can pass arguments to a main method only in above ways. If you don't want to hardcode the file path in your program, then try reading from user programmatically. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ways-to-read-input-from-console-in-java/